# Snowflake 'get' statement within stored procedure not working

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, java-stored-procedures

Problem statement: snowflake 'get' statement does not work inside a snowflake stored procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_UNLOAD_DYNAMIC("prefix" varchar)
    RETURNS varchar(1000)
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    EXECUTE AS CALLER
    AS
    $$
    var result  = "";

    try {
            
        var sql00   = "select concat('" + prefix + "', to_char(ts,'yyyymmddhh24miss'),'.txt') from ts";
        var stmt00  = snowflake.execute({ sqlText:sql00 });
        stmt00.next();
        var rs = stmt00.getColumnValue(1);
        
        var sql01   = "copy into @my_unload_stage/unload/" + rs + " from tmp_dedupe header=false single=true max_file_size=4900000000 overwrite=true;"
        var stmt01  = snowflake.execute({ sqlText:sql01 });
        stmt01.next();
           
        var sql02   = 'get @my_unload_stage file://D:\\project_x\\OutputFiles_STG\\';        
        var stmt02  =  snowflake.execute({ sqlText:sql02 });
        stmt02.next();
        
        result = rs;
        
    }
     
    catch (err)  {
        result =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
        result += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
        result += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt; 
    }
     
    return result;
    $$;
```

Everything seems works until stmt02. The get statement works in snowsql, but does not work in the stored procedure.

Thoughts, and thank you in advance.

-ibby

Comment: What's the error message you are getting? Does the file get populated or not i.e. is it the get statement that is failing or the "stmt02.next();" that is failing?

Comment: its the 'get' statement. when i checked the snowflake query logs, it shows processed. green check.

Comment: ok - so what's the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can execute a `GET` statement from within a stored procedure.  You'd be asking Snowflake to reach out to a client and move a file to that client.  How would a Snowflake VWH know where the client is to do that?

In order to do what you're doing, I believe you'd need to create an external application that leverages one of the Snowflake connectors, like Python, JDBC, ODBC, etc. that support `GET` and then maybe expose that in a Lambda or Azure function.  Then, you could call that API via a Snowflake External Function from within your Snowflake Stored Procedure.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions.html

Comment: The 'get' statement works when using snowsql, so I was thinking the connector info was passed through somehow.  Ultimately goal is replace the get statement to the local drive to a s3 bucket.

Comment: You'd definitely need to do that from outside the stored procedure.  Whatever that method is....like an API that does it....you could potentially call it from the SP with an external function, but you may also need it to be completely separate from the SP.  Like, if you were calling the SP from SnowSQL, you could execute the SP and then execute your GET as a separate step.